# Why rotating backwards is too fast, even if I set the time to 3 seconds?

Tags: unity, c#

The rotation is very fast. It takes less than a second and for sure not 3 seconds.

Maybe it's better to do it without using a coroutine? Or something in the `IEnumerator` is wrong with the time and progress calculation?

```
public IEnumerator DoRotate(float time)
{
    var newRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(180, Vector3.up) * transform.rotation;

    var progress = 0f;

    while (progress < 1)
    {
        progress += Time.deltaTime / time;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, progress);

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (rotateBackwards)
    {
        StartCoroutine(DoRotate(3f));
        rotateBackwards = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to cache your starting rotation, and rotate each frame relative to that starting point, rather than where you already advanced to:

```
public IEnumerator DoRotate(float time)
{
    var startRotation = transform.rotation;

    var newRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(180, Vector3.up) * transform.rotation;

    var progress = 0f;

    while (progress < 1)
    {
        progress += Time.deltaTime / time;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(startRotation, newRotation, progress);

        yield return null;
    }

    transform.rotation = newRotation;
}
```